# Wordpress featured image on hover - jQuery.Deferred exception: hrefValue is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, hover, wordpress-theming, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to make website which shows posts featured image on link hover.

Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsXWS.gif]

So I started to learn basic jQuery and php and I tried to achieve that by using `get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);` function which return image basing on post id. To get id I used `url_to_postid();` Wordpress function. As it states it: "Examine a URL and try to determine the post ID it represents." so the $url is required. So i thought I can deliver the variable by writing script, which gets 'href' from  on mouseover:

```
$('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
    var hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'))
   console.log(hrefValue)
});
```

And then, to pass this variable to php I used ajax jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'action': 'php_tutorial',
            'php_test': hrefValue
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("happy")
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately this is unsuccessful, because console returns:

> jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: hrefValue is not defined ReferenceError: hrefValue is not defined
>
> at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio/en/studio/:159:25)
> at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
> at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined

I wish someone would explain to me why or would tell me what's the best solution to achieve the desired effect.

Here is the full php file:

```
 <?php
get_header();
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
        var hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'))
       console.log(hrefValue)
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'action': 'php_tutorial',
            'php_test': hrefValue
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("happy")
        }
    });
}); 


</script>

<?php
function our_tutorial(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
        $testing = $_REQUEST['php_test'];

        echo 'This is our JS Variable :'.$testing;

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix.'lms_enroll',
            [
                'ID' => $testing
            ]
        );

    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial');
?>

<main id="primary" class="site-main">
<div class="container position-relative my-7">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" id="bio-box">
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio/2021/12/21/quod-si-ita-se-habeat-non-possit/">Example post link</a>
            <a href="http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio/2021/12/21/quid-ergo-aliud-intellege/">Example post link2</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <?php 
                    $post_id = url_to_postid($testing);
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

**1. Edit**
The problem with console has been resolved thx to @vee comment.

What I’m struggling with now is that function:

```
function our_tutorial(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST)){
        $testing = $_REQUEST['php_test'];

        echo 'This is our JS Variable :'.$testing;

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix.'lms_enroll',
            [
                'ID' => $testing
            ]
        );

    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial’);
```

it echos 'This is our JS Variable :’ but no $testing variable.

**2. Edit**

Again thx to @vee answer the problem with echo $testing is resolved. New and probably last thing have occurred. Wordpress Thumbnail still doesn't change.

Comment: Move `var hrefValue;` to outside document ready and use only `hrefValue = xxx` in the code. [Learn more about this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: thank you @vee, it solved console errors. The problem I am currently struggling with now is that the function "our_tutorial" echos 'This is our JS Variable:', but no $testing variable

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(hrefValue);` before `.ajax()`?

Comment: it shows url in console if mouse hover <a> @vee

Comment: That means if mouse out or when page just loaded without mouse over it, this `hrefValue` variable contain nothing. That is the problem. And while it has nothing in JS variable, you call to ajax with that nothing value. That is why `$_REQUEST['php_test']` not showing. To fix this, re-design the ajax process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error *jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: hrefValue is not defined* is because you did not declare variable in the scope that it can be access.

To fix this problem, move `var hrefValue;` to out side document ready.

[See JavaScript scope reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

```
var hrefValue;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
       hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'));// just use hrefValue = xx.
       console.log(hrefValue);
    });
});
```

Now JS error problem solved, your next problem is PHP can't retrieve value.
This is because JS variable `hrefValue` is `null` or nothing and you immediately make AJAX call to PHP.

To fix this, move AJAX process to where the `hrefValue` JS variable was assigned.

Example:

```
var hrefValue;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
        hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'));// just use hrefValue = xx.
        // if AJAX is here, it means it will working on mouse over.
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                'action': 'php_tutorial',
                'php_test': hrefValue
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("happy")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Everything make sens. Thank you. It echos the link from hover into ajax file now.

Comment: Another, and I hope the last problem have appeared. The wordpress thumbnail still doesnt change. While I simply `<?php echo $testing;?>` in html, it shows nothing.

Comment: @trz That really should be new question.

Comment: Yes. You are right, thanks once again

Comment: Could you link to the new question so this page has at least some value to people coming here trying to solve the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
var hrefValue; // define/declare global

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
// here just assign value
        hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'))
       console.log(hrefValue)
    });

});
```