# Function doesn't echo variable

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, echo

I'm currently learning basic php and jQuery.

I've created script which is getting url on mouse hover, and sends it to php.

The problem is, if I want to pass this data to php variable, it seems like it doesn't work because it echos only "'This is our JS Variable :'"

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
var hrefValue;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
        hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'))
       console.log(hrefValue)
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jakubtrz-portfolio/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            'action': 'php_tutorial',
            'php_test': hrefValue
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("happy")
        }
    });
}); 

</script>
```

functions.php:

```
function our_tutorial(){
        if(isset($_REQUEST)){
            $testing = $_REQUEST['php_test'];
    
            echo 'This is our JS Variable :'.$testing;
    
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->insert(
                $wpdb->prefix.'lms_enroll',
                [
                    'ID' => $testing
                ]
            );
        }
        die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_php_tutorial', 'our_tutorial');
```

Comment: `$_GET['php_test']` ?

Comment: still the same issue @Hast

Comment: Please show the result of `console.log(hrefValue);` and `print_r($_REQUEST);`.

Comment: if I move cursor over <a> `console.log(hrefValue);` is for example `http://localhost:8888/jakubtrz-portfolio/quid-ergo-aliud-intellege/` @vee

Comment: @trz `var_dump($_REQUEST)` is more important for the debugging here.

Comment: @hast `This is our JS Variable :array(1) { ["action"]=> string(12) "php_tutorial" } 0` if I've done it right

Comment: @trz I'm just answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482710/128761). Hope that fixed but you need to make sure that your ajax process is in correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was - when page loaded, value of a variable was empty. So solution is to call ajax in the moment of mouseover.

```
 var hrefValue;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#bio-box').find('a').mouseover(function() {
        hrefValue = ($(this).attr('href'))
        //console.log(hrefValue)
        $.ajax({
            url: frontendajax.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST', 
            data: {
                'action': 'image',
                'php_test': hrefValue
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#featured-image').html(data);
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'jakubtrz-portfolio/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post', // define type
        data: {
            'action': 'php_tutorial',
            'php_test': hrefValue
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("happy")
        }
    });


functions.php:
// post to et value
$test = $_POST['php_test'];
```